# Default Template Selected After Changes in Elementor

Tags: templates, page-template

I'm working with custom templates in WordPress. I'm using the Elementor plugin to build the site. When I open any page and make some changes in Elementor and then click the update button, I see that the default template is selected automatically.

**e.g** Before updating the page in Elementor I used the template "First Template" then I opened this page in Elementor and make some changes and then click the update button, after that when I saw that "Default template" was selected automatically. Why this is happening with me? how can I solve this issue? what should I do to avoid this?